# AngularJS ngKeyUp function the value is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**html**

```
<input class="input--style" type="email" name="email" ng-model="attempt.email" ng-keyup="check(attempt.email)" value="">
```

**angularjs**

```
$scope.check = function(text){
                            console.log(text);
                            $http({
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: '/api/user/check/',
                                data: {'email': $scope.attempt.email},
                                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},                 
                            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                console.log(data);
                                $scope.user.emailvalid = data.email;
                            });
                        }
```

This input is inside a modal and when the modal fires the angular above is inside that modals controller, it works as expected **but** when I start typing in the input field the `console.log(text);` outputs `undefined`

`$scope.attempt = {}` this is before my angular script above and I'm just curious as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Try using `check($parent.attempt.email)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really want to make a call to the server every time that the user presses a key? Wouldn't you prefer to have a `debounce` of at least ~200ms?

Try doing this instead:

```
<input class="input--style" type="email" name="email" 
     ng-model="attempt.email" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 200 }" 
     ng-change="check(attempt.email)" >
```

### Update:

I forgot to answer your original question: you are using an `input` `type="email"`, so unless it's a valid email angular will set the model to `undefined`. Therefore, angular is actually doing you a favor, because you probably don't want to make that call to the server unless the model contains a valid email address, right? So, just change your 'check' function so that it first checks if the value is `undefined` , and if it is don't make the call to the server and set `$scope.user.emailvalid` to `false`.

Comment: I actually just checked with a proper email, damn I cannot believe how silly that was. Just curious what does `debounce` do?

Comment: @Donald Have a look at **[this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)**. `Debounce` will make sure that the model doesn't get updated after a certain number of milliseconds have passed since the last user interaction. So, if the user is typing, it won't update the model until the user takes a pause. But in order to take advantage of that you need to use `ng-change`. Also, since this answer seems to solve your question I think that you should mark it as accepted. Thanks!